# java-graphql - Unable to match type definition with java type

Tags: spring, graphql, graphql-java

I am using graphql-spring-boot to serve graphql queries from my spring-boot project. Right now I am working on matching the graphql scheme type definitions with my spring entites. For whatever reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Unable to match type definition (ListType{type=TypeName{name='HomestayInfo'}}) with java type (class ninja.familyhomestay.domain.HomestayInfo): Java class is not a List or generic type information was lost: class ninja.familyhomestay.domain.HomestayInfo
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.TypeClassMatcher.error(TypeClassMatcher.kt:19)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match(TypeClassMatcher.kt:79)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.TypeClassMatcher.match(TypeClassMatcher.kt:25)
```

Here's my graphql schema defintion for `HomestayInfo`:

```
type HomestayInfo{
    homestayName: String
    homestayShortDescription: String
    homestayDescription: String
    address: Address
    rooms: [Room]
    houseImages: [HouseImage]
    pets: [Pet]
}
```

and the corresponding kotlin entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "homestay_info")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "homestay_info")
data class HomestayInfo(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "homestay_name")
    var homestayName: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "homestay_short_description")
    var homestayShortDescription: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "homestay_description")
    var homestayDescription: String? = null,

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    var address:Address?=null,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homestayInfo", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var rooms: MutableSet<Room> = HashSet(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homestayInfo", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var houseImages: MutableSet<HouseImage> = HashSet(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homestayInfo", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var pets: MutableSet<Pet> = HashSet()
) : Serializable
```

I don't see anything wrong with the mapping. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding scalar Date to the top of your schema.graphqls file should do the trick! So your file would look like such:

```
scalar Date

schema {           // not sure if your file has this, but mine does

   query: Query

}

type HomestayInfo{
...
```